# How to render template instead of throwing an error?

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, controller

I'm working on a plugin that hooks into Craft's Guest Entries plugin.

I want to send a confirmation mail after an entry has been saved. This works nicely so far.

Now I want to catch any errors in the mail service. This works nicely so far. Here's my code:

```
private function mailHandler($from, $to, $subject, $text)
{
    try
    {
        $message = new \craft\mail\Message;

        $message->setFrom($from);
        $message->setTo($to);
        $message->setSubject($subject);
        $message->setTextBody($text);

        Craft::$app->mailer->send($message);
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        echo \Craft::$app->view->renderTemplate('error', ['error' => 'Test']);
        die();
    }
}
```

There are two problems I'm facing:

1) I have to "stop" the controller action, that's why I need the `die`. This seems dirty though, is there any other way I could stop the controller?

2) If I do it like this, my error template is rendered, but without any CSS. What am I missing there?

Thanks a ton for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can see common patterns for this in Craft's own controllers.

For example in https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/master/src/controllers/EntriesController.php#L499-L507, if there's a problem, you can catch the error, set it on a route variable and `return null` so the original template can display it.

```
Craft::$app->getSession()->setError(Craft::t('app', 'Couldn’t duplicate entry.'));

// Send the original entry back to the template, with any validation errors on the clone
$entry->addErrors($clone->getErrors());
Craft::$app->getUrlManager()->setRouteParams([
    'entry' => $entry
]);

return null;
```

If you don't want to let the original template handle the error, then you should be able to do something like this from your controller:

```
return $this->renderTemplate('error', ['error' => 'Test']);
```